# How can I get the user ID of a test user created by a test fixture file? And how do I write an assertion using that users id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, fixtures, assertion

I have a form in an ERB file that ultimately submits a PATCH to the edit_user_path(@user). Here is the first line of code for the form (the only relevant part is the URL):

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, local:true, url: edit_user_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

which produces the following HTML:

```
<form action="/users/1/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
```

(Rails uses the hidden input with value="patch" to get around browsers not being able to actually do a PATCH)

(In the above example, I was editing user with id 1)

So now I have a PATCH to the edit_user_path(@user).

Now that my form is successfully creating the above HTML, I want to test for a very specific part of that HTML: `form action="/users/1/edit"`

My plan is to use an assertion but I am having trouble with how to write it or if it is even possible:

`assert_select 'form[action="/users/1/edit"]'`

the problem (I think) is that I am using fixtures to generate a user in the database. Here is the fixtures code (in the test/fixtures/users.yml file):

```
test_user:
  name: Mr. Test
  email: test@email.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

And here is the full test:

```
class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:test_user) # assinging @user to the user in my fixture file
  end

  test "Editing user with invalid user attributes" do
    patch edit_user_path(@user), params: {user: { name: "",
                                  email: "foo@invalid",
                                  password: "hey",
                                  password_confirmation: "ho"
                                }
                          }
    assert_select 'form[action="/users/???/edit"]'
  end
```

the problem (I think) I am running into is that I do not know what the user ID is for the user in my fixture file (`assert_select 'form[action="/users/1/edit"]'`)

does anyone know how to find the ID of a resource generated from fixtures? And also how to correctly construct the `assert_select 'form[action="/users/???/edit"]'` assertion?

Comment: But you have the user--if there's an associate id reference it in your URL string (e.g., interpolarion).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually creating a user - you need to use the fixture attributes to create one like

`@user = User.create(:test_user)`

Then you can access the created user's attributes, i.e. `@user.id`

For your assert_select URL string, you can just use string interpolation - http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html

`assert_select 'form[action="/users/#{@user.id}/edit"]'`